# Data menu and add Data Source in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In visual studio 2012 there is a Data menu option and add data source option that can be use to add a connection string to the app.config or the web.config. Where is that menu in Visual Studio 2015 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open data source window choose `View -> Other Windows -> Data Sources` as well you can try the short keys `Shift+Alt+D`.

Comment: As of today I cannot find the menu entry and the keyboard shortcut just expands the "Debug" menu.

Comment: @GigiSan, it depends on which version and type of VS you are in use.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, that's why I'm here. :)
But apparently I had [another problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180803/visual-studio-2015-add-new-data-source/38182714#38182714) so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Data sources window is not available for web applications, only available for windows forms and WPF applications in visual studio 2015.

you can use Server explorer instead.