# Visual Studio 2015 - Add new data source

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, datasource

I need to create a new data source starting from a custom object.

This seems possible in Visual Studio 2015 [as stated here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15.aspx) , but I can't find the `Project > Add New Data Source` menu entry.

I also tried:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776820/data-menu-and-add-data-source-in-visual-studio-2015) but the stated menu entry does not exist in VS2015 and the key shortcut just expands the `Debug` menu
- updating VS2015 to Update 3 enabling all components that seemed relevant to the matter
- creating a custom dataset, but VS always asks me for a DB connection

So far no luck in finding that dialog. 
Did anyone find it somewhere?

Thanks in advance for every advice!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot add a Data Source in web project using the Data Source Configuration Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022437/cannot-add-a-data-source-in-web-project-using-the-data-source-configuration-wiza)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022437/cannot-add-a-data-source-in-web-project-using-the-data-source-configuration-wiza).

You simply cannot add an object data source to web-type projects.
Instead, you must create an intermediate class library project in which you create the data source and then reference this new project in the web project.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try View -> Database Explorer. And in the database explorer, right click in some empty space and click Add Connection.

[image: View -> Database Explorer]

Comment: Not available for VS2017

Comment: Not available in Visual Studio 2019 either